# CSS wrap text around geometric images

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to wrap text around a christmas tree and have the text touch the edges?

I have a block of text on the left and a block of text on the right, I would like to put the tree in the middle and have text wrap around the left and right side edges, is this possible?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="left-text">
        <p class="left">Sed pretium dapibus lorem. Morbi sed diam eu dolor fermentum pharetra. Aliquam quis erat maximus ligula tincidunt tincidunt vel sed dolor. Curabitur sed aliquet mi. Morbi quis ipsum non ante consectetur varius. Fusce dapibus posuere metus, nec interdum ante. Curabitur magna odio, interdum at est nec, vulputate faucibus quam. Aliquam est nisi, ultricies in mauris quis, venenatis tristique urna. Integer tristique, orci lobortis egestas feugiat, enim massa hendrerit turpis, quis dictum purus tortor ac augue.</p>  
        <p class="left">Sed pretium dapibus lorem. Morbi sed diam eu dolor fermentum pharetra. Aliquam quis erat maximus ligula tincidunt tincidunt vel sed dolor. Curabitur sed aliquet mi. Morbi quis ipsum non ante consectetur varius. Fusce dapibus posuere metus, nec interdum ante. Curabitur magna odio, interdum at est nec, vulputate faucibus quam. Aliquam est nisi, ultricies in mauris quis, venenatis tristique urna. Integer tristique, orci lobortis egestas feugiat, enim massa hendrerit turpis, quis dictum purus tortor ac augue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-text">
        <p class="right">Sed pretium dapibus lorem. Morbi sed diam eu dolor fermentum pharetra. Aliquam quis erat maximus ligula tincidunt tincidunt vel sed dolor. Curabitur sed aliquet mi. Morbi quis ipsum non ante consectetur varius. Fusce dapibus posuere metus, nec interdum ante. Curabitur magna odio, interdum at est nec, vulputate faucibus quam. Aliquam est nisi, ultricies in mauris quis, venenatis tristique urna. Integer tristique, orci lobortis egestas feugiat, enim massa hendrerit turpis, quis dictum purus tortor ac augue.</p> 
        <p class="right">Sed pretium dapibus lorem. Morbi sed diam eu dolor fermentum pharetra. Aliquam quis erat maximus ligula tincidunt tincidunt vel sed dolor. Curabitur sed aliquet mi. Morbi quis ipsum non ante consectetur varius. Fusce dapibus posuere metus, nec interdum ante. Curabitur magna odio, interdum at est nec, vulputate faucibus quam. Aliquam est nisi, ultricies in mauris quis, venenatis tristique urna. Integer tristique, orci lobortis egestas feugiat, enim massa hendrerit turpis, quis dictum purus tortor ac augue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="christmas-tree"><img src="http://www.raidersleafs.com/images/christmas-tree.png" /></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main-content {

}

.main-content .left-text {
        width:25%;
        float:left;
}

.main-content .left-text p.left {
}

.main-content .right-text {
        width:25%;
        float:right;
}

.main-content .right-text p.right {
}

.main-content .christmas-tree {
        text-align: center;
}

.main-content .christmas-tree img {
        width: 90%;
}
```

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/63p19cbc/1/

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the left div of text to along the edge of the tree...still cant get the right side to do the same:

```
    .main-content .christmas-tree img {
    width: 90%;
    shape-outside: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 100%) content-box;
    float: right;
    }



    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="christmas-tree"><img src="http://www.raidersleafs.com/images/christmas-tree.png" /></div>
<div class="left-text">
            <p class="left">Sed pretium dapibus lorem. Morbi sed diam eu dolor fermentum pharetra. Aliquam quis erat maximus ligula tincidunt tincidunt vel sed dolor. Curabitur sed aliquet mi. Morbi quis ipsum non ante consectetur varius. Fusce dapibus posuere metus, nec interdum ante. Curabitur magna odio, interdum at est nec, vulputate faucibus quam. Aliquam est nisi, ultricies in mauris quis, venenatis tristique urna. Integer tristique, orci lobortis egestas feugiat, enim massa hendrerit turpis, quis dictum purus tortor ac augue.</p>  
            <p class="left">Sed pretium dapibus lorem. Morbi sed diam eu dolor fermentum pharetra. Aliquam quis erat maximus ligula tincidunt tincidunt vel sed dolor. Curabitur sed aliquet mi. Morbi quis ipsum non ante consectetur varius. Fusce dapibus posuere metus, nec interdum ante. Curabitur magna odio, interdum at est nec, vulputate faucibus quam. Aliquam est nisi, ultricies in mauris quis, venenatis tristique urna. Integer tristique, orci lobortis egestas feugiat, enim massa hendrerit turpis, quis dictum purus tortor ac augue.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-text">
            <p class="right">Sed pretium dapibus lorem. Morbi sed diam eu dolor fermentum pharetra. Aliquam quis erat maximus ligula tincidunt tincidunt vel sed dolor. Curabitur sed aliquet mi. Morbi quis ipsum non ante consectetur varius. Fusce dapibus posuere metus, nec interdum ante. Curabitur magna odio, interdum at est nec, vulputate faucibus quam. Aliquam est nisi, ultricies in mauris quis, venenatis tristique urna. Integer tristique, orci lobortis egestas feugiat, enim massa hendrerit turpis, quis dictum purus tortor ac augue.</p> 
            <p class="right">Sed pretium dapibus lorem. Morbi sed diam eu dolor fermentum pharetra. Aliquam quis erat maximus ligula tincidunt tincidunt vel sed dolor. Curabitur sed aliquet mi. Morbi quis ipsum non ante consectetur varius. Fusce dapibus posuere metus, nec interdum ante. Curabitur magna odio, interdum at est nec, vulputate faucibus quam. Aliquam est nisi, ultricies in mauris quis, venenatis tristique urna. Integer tristique, orci lobortis egestas feugiat, enim massa hendrerit turpis, quis dictum purus tortor ac augue.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/63p19cbc/2/

Comment: Here is a good article related to this question: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/63p19cbc/3/ I'm not sure if I understand what you want.

Comment: Similar to what @Godisgood did, you could have two columns of text. The right column would be limited by the left side of the tree, and the left column would be limited by the right side of the tree. You would need to write two separate polygons, one for each column.

Comment: You are close @Godisgood

Comment: what would those separate polygons looks like? Can you put it in an answer @Enigmadan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for ^^: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63p19cbc/5/). Do notice I changed the html in the JSFiddle a little bit.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-content">
            <div class="left">
                <p> In a one horse open sleigh.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right"> 
                <p>Oh the weather outside is frightful</p>
            </div>
    <img class="christmas-tree" src="http://www.raidersleafs.com/images/christmas-tree.png" />
        </div><!--main-content-->
```

**CSS**

```
.main-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
/*align image to center (horizontal) and place it by absolute positioning (so the
  image is always appearing on the same spot) after placing it we will create an
  empty spot so the text will appear to flow around the image*/
img.christmas-tree  {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 215px);
    width: 430px;
}
/*Just some text assigned to the right div*/
.right{
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
/*We will create empty space where the christmas tree is by adding blank content
 with ::before*/
.right::before{
    content: "";
    height: 550px;
    shape-outside: polygon(50px 0, 50px 150px, 215px 550px, 0 550px);/*this cuts out
        a part of the block so the text can freely move around. The values in here
        are coördinates in this blank content that allow text to float around it.*/
    width: 100%;
    float: left;    
}
.left{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
}
/*We will create empty space where the christmas tree is by adding blank content
  with ::before*/
.left::before{
    content: "";
    shape-outside: polygon(450px 0px, 450px 150px, 270px 550px, 500px 550px); /*this
                     cuts out a part of the block so the text can freely move around*/
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

A few final notes:

- The polygon is kinda hard to explain, but you basically add some points (imagine lines between the points) to "cut" out some part of a block or image. [The site Chris Hollenbeck recommended](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/#toc-polygon) explains it better than I can.
- A big part of my solution relies on knowing exact coordinates of the christmas-tree. To make it work with a flexible size tree will be a lot harder.
- I expect many browsers do not support `shape-outside:`. If you know what browsers do and do not leave a comment ^^.

Comment: As suggested, this is using two columns of text, the left column is being affected by the right side of the tree using a pseudo-element `::before` and the right column is being affected by the left side of the tree using the pseudo-element `::before`. My solution was going to be much less elegant. Props to you!

Comment: +1, but [woeful browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes) - only in webkit (Chrome, Safari) and Opera